# facebook ignited

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

In the welcome_view.php I can’t view my name even though I’m already logged in Facebook.

this is my setup:

```
config/fb_ignited.php

$config['fb_appid']     = 'myid';

$config['fb_secret'] = 'mysecret';

$config['fb_canvas'] = 'dean_test';

$config['fb_apptype'] = 'connect';

$config['fb_auth'] = '';
```

now on my dev.facebook setup

```
App Display Name:Dean Mobile Application

App Namespace:dean_test
Website
Site URL: mydomain.com/dean_test/
```

Supposedly when Im currently logged in it should show: Welcome **Dean**, to Facebook Ignited but it show me: Welcome, to Facebook Ignited

Answer (score 2):

in my fb_canvas I wrote the Site URL, try:

```
$config['fb_canvas'] = 'http://mydomain.com/dean_test/'
```

Answer (score 0):

As according to the updated config file within my project at the [Facebook Ignited GitHub](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited/) you will find a new comment there that shows examples for the iframe and connect as below:

```
/**
 * --- fb_canvas examples ---
 * iframe       your-facebook-namespace 
 * connect      www.your-connect-domain.com/subfolder/
 */
```

You only need the namespace if you are using an iframe app. If you are using connect you will just need everything after `http(s)://` from the address.